# How to initialise options menu checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-optionsmenu

I have an options menu with a checkbox. I can check and uncheck the checkbox when it has been clicked by the user which is fine. However, I am using SharedPreferences to store the value of this checkbox, so what I also need to do is to initialise the checkbox with whatever is stored in the SharedPreferences pref value i.e. if the pref is true/false, set the checkbox to checked/unchecked.

I guess I need to put some code inside my onCreateOptionsMenu, and I obviously need to use .setChecked(preference) to set the checkbox, but how do I programatically reference the checkbox itself?

The menu is created using:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

The checkbox can be checked/unchecked using:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.two_week:
            if (item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the only method that you are missing is Menu's findItem(). You can easily load any SharedPreferences (called `prefs` here) like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
...

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    boolean checked = prefs.getBoolean("two weeks", false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.two_week).setChecked(checked);
    return true;
}
```